# My Scale Controller Software fails to read the scale after around 5 minutes of being connected

Tags: rust, usb, hid

I've created some software to control USB scales using the `hidusb` crate. Heres a general overview of my control flow:
Each frame of the app (10 per second):

- Get the HidApi singleton.
- Open the Hid Device with hid.open(vendor_id, product_id)
- Read Raw Data - Fails here after 5 minutes!
- Parse and send data

```
// Connect to the scale
pub fn connect(vendor_info: VendorInfo) -> ScaleResult<Self> {
    let VendorInfo { vendor_id, product_id } = vendor_info;
    match HidApi::new() {
        Ok(hid) => match hid.open(vendor_id, product_id) {
            Ok(device) => Ok(Self { device, vendor_info }),
            Err(err) => Err(ScaleError::ConnectError(err)),
        },
        Err(err) => Err(ScaleError::UsbError(err)),
    }
}
```

```
// Read Raw Data
fn read_raw(&self) -> ScaleResult<ByteBuffer> {
        let mut buf: ByteBuffer = [0u8; DATA_SIZE];
        for _ in 0..RECONNECT_ATTEMPTS {
            let result = self.device.read_timeout(&mut buf[..], 10);
            if let Ok(size) = result {
                if size == DATA_SIZE {
                    return Ok(buf);
                }
            }
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
        }

        println!("Buffer: {:?}", buf);
        Err(ScaleError::ReadError)
    }
```

The data is later parsed. After 5 minutes of using the scale, it gives me `ScaleError::ReadError` every frame. Unplugging the scale and replugging it in fixes it. I was guessing it was windows powering down the USB port but this is happening even after configuring the power settings.
Anyone have any ideas and can help me out? Thanks!

I've tried modifying Windows power settings. Sending a "heartbeat" to the scale echoing what it sent me.

Comment: Opening the device 10 times per second doesn't sound great.  I hope you're remembering to close it 10 times per second too.  Even if you are, I wonder if you're running into some weird Windows limit.  It might better to keep the handle open and reuse it as much as possible.

Comment: Ok sounds good. I did that so I could instantly be aware of if the USB port was disconnected. I could probably refactor it to maintain the scale unless there is a read error. I use a context manager so the connection is closed when the handler goes out of scope. Do you think it would be a problem to attempt to connect 10 times a second if it fails? I like the way it works currently where when the user plugs in the scale it instantly connects. Or maybe there is a USB event system I could tap into? I'm a beginner to the USB protocol.

Comment: I don't know what the limits are or what's OK, we're just guessing here.  If it's reliably failing after 5 minutes, maybe you could do some simple experiments first to verify that opening it so many times is causing trouble.  Like if you open it twice per frame, does it fail in 2.5 minutes?  If you change the frame time to 0.2 seconds, does it fail in 10 minutes?

Comment: Another question, is there a practical guide for interacting with HID devices? I've googled around and have only found extremely in depth RFCs or surface level tutorials. Is there anything that goes over all the things a day to day dev would need to know?

Comment: Just a thought: I'm assuming it is a battery operated scale that measures human body weight? It may have been programmed to go into low power mode after a certain time. It may even have a watchdog timer that resets the microcontroller to recover from runaway looping. Both scenarios could cause the behaviour that you are experiencing.

Comment: Interesting thought, we have a 3rd party software that is able to read the scale fine after hours of time. They might be handling it slightly different from I. Not sure if relevant, but my software "captures" the USB port, meaning if another software tries to use it,  is is denied. Does that mean anything? Also I followed David's suggestions, maintaining a long running connection to the scale and only attempting to reconnect on failure every 5 seconds. I use the software on Linux as well and do not run into the same issue (I've configured custom USB config for my Linux box though.)

Comment: It might be worth capturing a long running Wireshark trace of the 3rd party software's traffic to see whether it sends some kind of keep alive messages.